# vb 6 can't Open form Path/File Access Error: filepath.log

Tags: vb6

So i tried to open a specific form in vb 6 it says Path/File Access Error "filepath.log";

when i tried to open the log file this is the content

```
Line 2: Could not create reference: '{90F3D7B3-92E7-44BA-B444-6A8E2A3BC375}#1.0#0'.
Line 3: Could not create reference: '{6B7E6392-850A-101B-AFC0-4210102A8DA7}#1.3#0'.
```

is there a way to open that specific form. I can open other forms in the project.

**UPDATE**

I tried Opening The .vbp project file in notepad and found the source of the reference.

```
Object={90F3D7B3-92E7-44BA-B444-6A8E2A3BC375}#1.0#0; actskin4.ocx
Object={6B7E6392-850A-101B-AFC0-4210102A8DA7}#1.3#0; COMCTL32.OCX
```

still i don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Now your update is a much better piece of info. You need to get those ocx files and put them in your `bin` folder. The `comctl32.ocx` is some standard MS file (MS Common Controls), and I think I still have it somewhere in my pre-historic projects, but I have no idea about the `actskin4.ocx`. Perhaps some 3rd party library. Hmm, just checked, the one I have is `mscomct2.ocx`, must be a newer or older version of it.

Comment: i can open the file wheni put it in window/system32. Thanks

Comment: That likely means that you have those two files on your computer in the window/system32 folder, but perhaps somehow not registered properly. You can either register them or perhaps copy them to the project's folder to see if it will help opening the form there instead of the window/system32 folder.

Answer (score 2):

The VB6 IDE will generally refuse to display a form if one or more of the controls on the form cannot be loaded.

(You can of course view the `.frm` file in a text editor if you just need to read some detail of the code.)

Based on the combined information from the log file and the `.VBP` it seems clear that the two OCX files listed *are not registered on your development PC*. They may or may not be physically present.

As a first step, I would search on the PC to see if they can be located. Typically OCX files would be installed into the `\Windows\SysWOW64` or `\Windows\System32` folders, although other locations are definitely possible.

(`COMCTL32.OCX` is a Microsoft file, so that is probably where you'll find it. I don't know what the other one is).

- Assuming you find those files, most likely you can register them in the location you find them (there are a lot of possibilities but that is probably an OK start).
- If you can't locate them you will have to find some copy (from another developer maybe?) before you can proceed. If `actskin4.ocx` is a professional 3rd party control then probably it would have come with a proper installer which you should located & run.

[Here are Microsoft's instructions to manually register a DLL / OCX](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/146219/how-to-register-an-activex-control--ocx-manually).